# Logging Sass with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js

Is there some way Next.js can log the Sass rules such as @debug, @error, @warn?

I've tried:

```
$base-color: #c6538c;
@debug "base color: #{$base-color}";
```

But don't see anything in the terminal. Not sure if I'm looking in the wrong place or it's just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out a while back, so if anyone's curious here it is:

Next.js will only output the Sass @error. If you need to use @debug or @warn, you'll need to compile your .sass/.scss file, i.e.:

```
sass --watch input.scss output.css
```